# Image of the Ionic app icon displayed cropped after generating the apk

Tags: cordova, gradle, ionic4, capacitor

[ **Contextualizing the problem** ]

I have an Ionic PWA project in production.

 I need to generate Android apps using the same project and I am using capacitor to generate apps and resources.

 Apk files were created correctly, but the application icon was not. When using the default app icon (capacitor icon) it works, when using the custom icon, the image is cut.

Original (512x512)
[image]

Icon was like this
[image: icon_like_this]

[ **Scripts** ]

Below are the steps to generate. 
 The configuration is ok, at first. All scripts run without alerts.

Generate resources

```
> cordova-res android --skip-config --copy
```

All resources are created and in the correct sizes for each dimension.
[image]

Generate APKs

```
> ng build --prod && ionic cap copy android && cd android && gradlew assemble && cd ..
```

[image]

[ **Configuration** ]

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16 (C:\Users\rpizao\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.16.1\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.3.4
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1000.8
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.0.8
   @angular/cli                  : 10.0.8
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : 2.4.2
   @capacitor/core : 2.4.2

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 9.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : not available

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.3
   native-run  : 1.3.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 25.2.3 (D:\apps\Android)
   NodeJS            : v12.16.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.13.4
   OS                : Windows 10
```

Comment: you need 1024*1024 icon size

Comment: Running 'cordova-res android --skip-config --copy', the minimum is 512.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dimensions created are the same in both solutions, but using `cordova-res` my icons are generated without correct border for icon round.

Using a web solution like https://easyappicon.com works.